# Error al ejecutar consulta preparada

Tags: php, mysql

```
$user = $_COOKIE['c_username'];       
$filter = filter_var($_POST['buscar_inventario'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$query = "SELECT 
                     Inv_Id, 
                     Inv_Ref, 
                     Inv_Name, 
                     Inv_Desc, 
                     Inv_Purch_Price, 
                     Inv_Sale_Price, 
                     Inv_Quant, 
                     Inv_Date, 
                     Inv_Public 
                 FROM inventory 
                 WHERE 
                     Inv_User = :user 
                     AND Inv_Name LIKE %:filter% 
                     OR Inv_Desc LIKE %:filter% 
                     OR Inv_Ref LIKE %:filter% 
                     OR Inv_Purch_Price LIKE %:filter% 
                     OR Inv_Sale_Price LIKE %:filter% 
                 ORDER BY Inv_Ref ASC 
                 LIMIT 20";

$result = $base -> prepare($query);
$result -> bindValue(':user', $user);
$result -> bindValue(':filter', $filter);
$result -> execute();
```

El error que me genera es el siguiente:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'producto'% OR Inv_Desc LIKE %'producto'% OR Inv_Ref LIKE %'producto'% OR Inv_P' at line 1

¿Es posible que me salga el error por el uso de `%:filter%`?

Comment: Si. Intenta poner los carácteres del like `%` en el filter,algo como `$filter ='%' +  filter_var($_POST['buscar_inventario'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) + '%';` y quitarles de tu query

Comment: @Pikoh - Pon ese comentario como respuesta... es la más acertada

Comment: @aldanux en realidad la tenía preparada, pero como no soy experto en php pensé que sería mas adecuada y completa la de Oscar Garcia. Respuesta añadida de todas maneras :)

Comment: Ups, la verdad es que no vi tu comentario mientras redactaba @Pikoh, pero también es otra solución al problema :) te llevas mi +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las consultas preparadas no soportan el uso de variables con nombre como parte de una cadena, debes usar una de las siguientes soluciones:

## Función PHP [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/pdo.quote)

Con esta solución escaparemos el contenido de la variable `$filter` para insertarla directamente en la consulta SQL:

```
/* Aquí debes usar tu instancia de conexión PDO */
$filter = '%' . $pdo->quote(
  filter_var($_POST['buscar_inventario'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
) . '%';

$query = "
  SELECT
    Inv_Id,
    Inv_Ref,
    Inv_Name,
    Inv_Desc,
    Inv_Purch_Price,
    Inv_Sale_Price,
    Inv_Quant,
    Inv_Date,
    Inv_Public
  FROM inventory
  WHERE
    Inv_User = :user
  AND
    (
      Inv_Name LIKE $filter
    OR
      Inv_Desc LIKE $filter
    OR
      Inv_Ref LIKE $filter
    OR
      Inv_Purch_Price LIKE $filter
    OR
      Inv_Sale_Price LIKE $filter
    )
  ORDER BY Inv_Ref ASC LIMIT 20
";

$result = $base->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(':user', $_COOKIE['c_username']);
$result->execute();
```

Nota: La función agrega las comillas externas.

## Función SQL [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Esta solución hace uso de la función SQL `CONCAT` para montar la cadena que será comparada mediante el operador `LIKE`:

```
$query = "
  SELECT
    Inv_Id,
    Inv_Ref,
    Inv_Name,
    Inv_Desc,
    Inv_Purch_Price,
    Inv_Sale_Price,
    Inv_Quant,
    Inv_Date,
    Inv_Public
  FROM inventory
  WHERE
    Inv_User = :user
  AND
    (
      Inv_Name LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')
    OR
      Inv_Desc LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')
    OR
      Inv_Ref LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')
    OR
      Inv_Purch_Price LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')
    OR
      Inv_Sale_Price LIKE CONCAT('%', :filter, '%')
    )
  ORDER BY Inv_Ref ASC LIMIT 20
";

$result = $base->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(':user', $_COOKIE['c_username']);
$result->bindValue(
  ':filter',
  filter_var($_POST['buscar_inventario'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
);
$result->execute();
```

## Incluir los comodines en el valor

Con esta solución agregamos el patrón dentro de la variable asignada al SQL:

```
$query = "
  SELECT
    Inv_Id,
    Inv_Ref,
    Inv_Name,
    Inv_Desc,
    Inv_Purch_Price,
    Inv_Sale_Price,
    Inv_Quant,
    Inv_Date,
    Inv_Public
  FROM inventory
  WHERE
    Inv_User = :user
  AND
    (
      Inv_Name LIKE :filter
    OR
      Inv_Desc LIKE :filter
    OR
      Inv_Ref LIKE :filter
    OR
      Inv_Purch_Price LIKE :filter
    OR
      Inv_Sale_Price LIKE :filter
    )
  ORDER BY Inv_Ref ASC LIMIT 20
";

$result = $base->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(':user', $_COOKIE['c_username']);
$result->bindValue(
  ':filter',
  '%' . $pdo->quote(
    filter_var($_POST['buscar_inventario'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
  ) . '%'
);
$result->execute();
```

Nota: Gracias [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la pista.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `:filter` se añade como una cadena al query,con sus comillas sencillas. De esa manera la parte del like queda como `%'tufiltro'%`, lo que no es correcto. Si concatenas los comodines en tu filtro y los quitas de la query funcionará correctamente:

```
$user = $_COOKIE['c_username'];       
$filter = '%' + filter_var($_POST['buscar_inventario'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) + '%';

$query = "SELECT Inv_Id, Inv_Ref, Inv_Name, Inv_Desc, Inv_Purch_Price, Inv_Sale_Price, Inv_Quant, Inv_Date, Inv_Public FROM inventory WHERE Inv_User = :user AND Inv_Name LIKE :filter OR Inv_Desc LIKE :filter OR Inv_Ref LIKE :filter OR Inv_Purch_Price LIKE :filter OR Inv_Sale_Price LIKE :filter ORDER BY Inv_Ref ASC LIMIT 20";

$result = $base -> prepare($query);
$result -> bindValue(':user', $user);
$result -> bindValue(':filter', $filter);
$result -> execute();
```